# Error trying to get property 'users' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have a problem, i am doing a shift history of the user logged in the application.

```
@foreach($eventos as $evento)
  if($evento->solicitud->users->id == (Auth::user()->id))
    <div class="item-timeline">
      <div class="t-meta-date">
        <p class="">{{$evento->fecha}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="t-dot">
      </div>
      <div class="t-text">
        <p>{{$evento->servicio->servicio}}</p>
        <p>{{$evento->personal}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

I get all shifts with:

```
  public function perfil (){

    $eventos = Eventos::All();
  

    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'users',
        'page_name' => 'profile',
        'has_scrollspy' => 0,
        'scrollspy_offset' => '',

    ];
    // $pageName = 'profile';
    return view('users.user_profile',compact('eventos'))->with($data);
}
```

Model Eventos:

```
public function solicitud()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Solicitudes::class);
}
```

Model Solicitudes:

```
 public function evento()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Eventos::class);
}
```

and then filter with if condition.

But it shows me error `Trying to get property 'users' of non-object`

dd capture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFzzn.png

data base: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gahr5.png

I need to get the **User_id** from the **solicitudes** table.

The relation is: **Eventos** table-> solicitud_id with the **ID** column of the **Solicitudes** table.

Comment: Did you try with  $evento['solicitud']?

Comment: try and give the same error @if ($ event ['request'] -> user_id == (Auth :: user () -> id))

Comment: Do you fetch data from this $eventos=Eventos::all() .. without using with('solicitud.users')?

Comment: I'm sorry , few things are not clear . Will you mind sharing controller and relations in model class ?

Comment: Yes, i update my post

Comment: do you have users function in solicitudes class?

Comment: I do not understand your question, i am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code which you have provided, `$evento-> solicitud-> users` means I assume that you have used a nested relationship and the following things are missing

1. there is no 'users' relation in 'solicitudes' class
2. you didn't call relations in controller while fetching eventos (that is `$eventos=Eventos::with('solicitud.users')->get()`

correct me if my assumption is wrong

Comment: the assumption is correct, how do I make the relation of users in 'solicitudes' class?

Comment: you can make it like this 

`
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');
    }
`
 replace user_id with the foreign-key of user's table in solicitudes table

Comment: still with the same error, but dd () if it shows the value of the user's id.

Comment: @if($evento->solicitud_id !== Null) add one more if condition and the problem is solved, thanks for your help